# Get selected option text using react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have my select list component rendering my select list:

```
<form className="pure-form">
<select ref="selectMark" className="mark-selector"
 onChange={this.onChange}>{this.getOptions()}
</select>
</form>
```

I have a method on the component to create the options:

```
getOptions: function () {
    return this.props.renderProps.data.map(function (item) {
        return <option key={item.value} value={item.value}>{item.label}</option>;
    }.bind(this));

},
```

My onChange method works fine with the value:

```
onChange: function(event) {
    var newValue = event.nativeEvent.target.value;
    this.props.renderProps.onSaveCare(newValue);
    this.setState({value: newValue});
    this.toggleEdit();
},
```

Is there a way I can get the option text? This gives me undefined

```
event.nativeEvent.target.text; //undefined
```

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Something like this should do

```
var index = event.nativeEvent.target.selectedIndex;
event.nativeEvent.target[index].text
```

Here is a demo **http://jsbin.com/vumune/4/**

Comment: God bless you!!

Comment: Hi @Dhiraj, It is working with event.target.value also, so why above?

Comment: @user10742206 : incase if something else is assigned to "value" then its useful.

Answer (score 55):

You can get the option text by replacing this:

```
event.nativeEvent.target.text;
```

with this:

```
event.target.options[event.target.selectedIndex].text
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

If it's single select, here is more simple way:

`e.target.selectedOptions[0].text`

Comment: Worked with Vue!

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me

```
const {options, value} = e.target;
console.log(options[value].innerHTML);
```

Edit: I just realized I was using the "value" field to store the ID of some objects, from 0 to n. I guess a better approach could be the following:

```
const {options, selectedIndex} = e.target;
console.log(options[selectedIndex].innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 3):

The text of an option is simply the `label` property of the corresponding `item`.

In your case, to retrieve the text of the selected option, you can do:

```
var selectedItem = this.props.renderProps.data.find(function (item) {
  return item.value === event.target.value;
});
selectedItem.label;
```

[`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) is part of the ES6 proposal. Underscore or lodash already package it as the [`_.find` method](https://lodash.com/docs#find).

Answer (score 2):

> Here what i do to retrieve the text from select option in react js.

```
this.refs.selectMark[this.refs.selectMark.value].text
```

Answer (score 2):

It's easy using refs.

import the hook

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
```

instantiate it

```
const yourNewRef= useRef();
```

Reference it in your element

```
ref={yourNewRef}
```

Then you can access it in any event or function by simply calling:

```
let textSelectOption = yourNewRef.current.options[yourNewRef.current.selectedIndex].text
```

You can access the value simply by calling

```
let optionValue = yourNewRef.current.value
```

refs are great, you can do almost everything you would using jQuery.
Take a look at yourNewRef on console and access all the content via the .current property

Answer (score 1):

2020 and this Worked For Me

My Select Element :

```
          <FormGroup>
                  {<Select
                    closeMenuOnSelect={true}
                    components={animatedComponents}
                    options={Options}
                    value = "Ahmedabad"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    name = "citySelect"
                  />}
          </FormGroup>
```

Call handler :

```
handleChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.value)
}
```

Comment: butwhat happend  if you need the value as a number and get the text inside the option tag?

Answer (score 1):

change your menu item accordingly

Current / Temporary address
Permanent address
Office / Business Address

and on change event get

```
onChange = {(e,index)  =>
( setAddressChangeType(e.target.value),  console.log(index.props.id) )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

make your dropdown accordingly and get value on change event like

```
onChange = {(e,index)  =>
( setAddressChangeType(e.target.value),  console.log(index.props.id) )
}
```