# Select box and getting the option label

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a dropdown box with the following structure

```
<select 
     name="propertytype"
     value={this.state.propertytype}
     onChange={this.handlePropertyTypeChange}>
     <option value="">Property Type</option>
     <option value="T">Terrace</option>
     <option value="F">Flat</option>
     <option value="S">Semi</option>
     <option value="D">Detached</option>
</select>
```

the handle function looks like this - I can obtain the value of the dropdown with e.target.value --- but I need to obtain the label - so instead of "F" I need "Flat".

```
handlePropertyTypeChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({propertytype: e.target.value});
}
```

-- I have tried obtaining it using e.target.nodeName

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript:

```
var el = document.getElementByName('prototypetype');
var text = el.options[el.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
```

With JQuery:

```
$('select option:selected').text();
```

With React event:

```
var index = event.nativeEvent.target.selectedIndex;
event.nativeEvent.target[index].text
```

See the demo from @Dhiraj Bodicherla: [Get selected option text using react js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30306486/get-selected-option-text-using-react-js)

Comment: well its using reactjs -- isn't there a way to obtain the value via the event ?

Comment: Yes, @Dhiraj Bodicherla has some demo which I put in answer.

Comment: var index = event.nativeEvent.target.selectedIndex;
event.nativeEvent.target[index].text

Comment: you did it? I'm not specialist in react.js, for this I quote @Dhiraj