# setState to the current item selected from dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
var Dummy= React.createClass({
onSelect: function(e) {
   this.setstate({ selectedItem: e.currentTarget.value })
},
render: function() {
    return <select onChange={this.onSelect.bind(this)}>
             <option value="1">Item 1</option>
             <option value="2">Item 2</option>
             <option value="3">Item 3</option>
           </select>
    }
});
```

In the code above I'm trying to set state to the current item selected from the dropdown. I know an easy way of doing it is `e.currentTarget.value` but it returns  the `value` of the clicked item. I want the inner text (ie, Item 1, 2 etc.)

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can set the `value` prop to the same as the text.

Comment: i dont want to do that. i want the `value` attribute to be different than the text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get selected option text using react js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30306486/get-selected-option-text-using-react-js)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `text`:

```
this.setstate({ selectedItem: e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].text })
```